# How could I use my second laptop to extend my laptop's screen?

Tags: screen, 16.10

I was wondering how I could create a dummy or fake monitor that I could use to extend my display. Then I wanted to use vnc to connect to the dummy screen with my other laptop. If someone has something easier or better please suggest it. I'm using normal unity Ubuntu 16.10 on both.
It's been done on windows as see here.
- https://youtu.be/W9gAlqCX5Lw

I've also tried xdmx but it didn't work for me. It would give me a "(Fatal Error) dmx: InitOutput: no back-end displays found" error after I ran xdmx :1

Comment: It can't be done would be my hypotheses.

Comment: why? It's been done with windows.

Comment: Interesting. *How* is it done with Windows? Can you please point to a link?

Comment: https://youtu.be/W9gAlqCX5Lw It's from 2015 and the guy used fedora to vnc into the windows pc.

Comment: I suggest you edit and add that to your question. And wait for answers.

Comment: It should be possible for you to use 'VNC' like in the youtube video clip, but between two Ubuntu computers. Once you have set it up, it would be rather convenient. - There is a rather old but I think good help page for Ubuntu with many links, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC - There are also wikipedia pages, that can help you find alternatives or forks, for example 'TightVNC'. I used VNC very long ago, and I don't know which alternative is the best nowadays, but I think most of them work.

Answer (score -1):

Check the laptop manufacturer information online. Most laptops only have their video card sources (HDMI, DVI, VGA, etc.) set to output only, but that is not always the case.

For the case of Ubuntu, if you can't use your laptop using those cables, a networked connection is possible. It seems that [XDMX](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/Xdmx.1.html) is the best possible route but it seems difficult to set up.
There is also [Synergy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto), but that's not exactly the same thing. Synergy works by allowing use of one keyboard and mouse across multiple computers.

Comment: I got synergy working but that's not exactly what I wanted. I tried xdmx but it didn't work for me. It would give me a "(Fatal Error) dmx: InitOutput: no back-end displays found" error.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with xdmx to help. It just seemed like a worthwhile option.